# Как создать расширяемый js-функционал?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп, плагин

Допустим на нескольких страницах сайта есть повторяемый функционал в виде аккордеона, реализуемый с помощью jquery-функции `slideToggle()`.
Ниже примерный код аккордеона:
https://jsfiddle.net/t8h1ajom/5/

```js
var $block = $('.block');
$block.on('click', function(e){
    var $title = $(e.target).closest('.block__title'),
 $content = $title.next();
    $content.slideToggle(500);
})
```

```css
.block{
  position: relative;
}
.block__title{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block__content{
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__title">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="block__content">
    content
    <div class="element">some element</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Интересует вопрос: как можно добавлять новый функционал в уже существующий, не создавая заново велосипед?
 т.е. допустим на других страницах нужен такой-же аккордеон, но плюс ещё нужно сделать дополнительные манипуляции с элементами аккордеона.
Интересует объектно-ориентированный вариант, благодаря которому можно было бы легко добавлять новый функционал в уже существующий.
Как нужно переписать существующий js-код о объектно-ориентированный?
Может быть как-то реализовать в виде jquery-плагина?
Очень надеюсь на помощь от знающих людей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модульность - ключ к успеху.
Нужно удержать баланс между минимальной связностью и объективно лишним дроблением.

Так же помогают хуки, прототипы, примеси, харизма и обаяние :)

```js
/**
 * Простейшая реализация системы хуков
 */
class Hook{
  constructor(){
    this._hooks = {};
  }
  
  listen(name, fn){
    if(!(name in this._hooks))
      this._hooks[name] = [];
      
    this._hooks[name].push(fn);
  }
  
  fire(name, ...args){debugger;
    if(!(name in this._hooks))
      return;
      
    this._hooks[name].forEach(fn => fn.apply(null, args))
  }
}

let hook = new Hook();

var $block = $('.block');
$block.on('click', function(e){
   var $title = $(e.target).closest('.block__title'),
  $content = $title.next();
   hook.fire('toggle', $title, $content);
   $content.slideToggle(500);
});

hook.listen('toggle', function(title, content){
    console.info("Кто-то хочет открыть (или закрыть) слайдер? :)");
});
```

```css
.block{
  position: relative;
}
.block__title{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block__content{
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__title">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="block__content">
    content
    <div class="element">some element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: благодарю за пример, но хотелось бы уточнить. Получается, что hook.listen() нужно вызывать на каждой странице отдельно, чтобы задать нужный функционал для конкретной страницы? А как сделать, если js-файл всего один для всех страниц сразу? Нужно как-то различать страницы

Comment: @word, Есть один файл, в котором вызывается хук. В нужных страницах подключаете дополнительный файл со специфическим дополнением. Если нужно отличать страницы - проверяйте `location.href`, например.

Comment: а чтобы не подключать дополнительный файл, одним js-файлом можно это сделать? различать страницы, я имел ввиду различать разные аккордеоны на разных страницах, т.к. url страницы может поменяться в php

Comment: получается, каждый аккордеон нужно идентифицировать с помощью id или класса, и в js-скрипте проверять текущий блок? Тут наверно проще сделать jquery-плагином? Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: js файл всего один для всего сайта, т.к. фреймворк сжимает все скрипты в один после сборки проекта

Comment: @word, если честно, я не пойму что Вам нужно. В один файл нужно сжимать только те части, которые нужны везде. Остальные лучше подключать отдельно. Так ядро кэшировать можно, а в HTTP/2 особо не важно что несколько файлов будет.

Comment: фреймворк не я создавал, в один файл сжимаются все js. Разве нельщя как-то различать разные аккордеоны в одном скрипте? по идее это не такая уж редкая ситуация. может быть в этом коде hook.fire('toggle', $title, $content); вместо toggle передавать переменную? подскажите, как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: @word, если так уж приспичило, можете в разных аккордионах передавать разные метки типа `hook.fire('toggle', 'fromFooter')`, `hook.fire('toggle', 'fromHeaven')`, а в слушателе проверять: `hook.listen('toggle', from => { if(from === 'fromFooter') ... })`.